# Turns warnings into errors in Ember.JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to throw warnings as errors in Ember application. I found

```
Ember.ENV.RAISE_ON_DEPRECATION = true
```

but as I understand it works only for depreciation warning.
I want to throw warnings like

> "WARNING: Binding style attributes may introduce cross-site scripting vulnerabilities; please ensure that values being bound are properly escaped. For more information, including how to disable this warning, see http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_warning-when-binding-style-attributes30."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Ember.Logger.warn` or `Ember.warn`. The differences between the two is that the second in a production build, is defined as an empty function.

`Ember.Logger.warn`seems undocumented but you can give a look at the source code https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-console/lib/index.js#L81.

Docs for `Ember.warn`: http://emberjs.com/api/#method_warn